# JavaScript alert is not showing in browser

Tags: javascript, css, html

I can't seem to figure out why an alert won't show in the browser. I am using Chrome with Yosemite.

Here is my code in the script.js file:

```
$ (document).one('pageinit', function() {
  // add handler
  $ ('#submitAdd').on('tap', addWalk) ;
  // add a walk
  function addWalk() {
    alert (1);
  }
);
```

And here is the top of index.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Miletracker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
    <script scr="js/script.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function(){
        $('.date') .each(function(){
          $(this) .datepicker();
        })
      });
    </script>
  </head>
```

Comment: You should put your JS after your HTML, a good option is to put it at the end of your body tag just before you close it, might fix it

Comment: You misspelt `src` as `scr` (voting to close the question as the problem is caused by a typo). Please learn to format your code on Stackoverflow, and to use your browser's developer tools to see if your script is actually being loaded (the Net tab) and if there are any errors (the Console tab). See also [markup validators](http://validator.w3.org/nu/) which would have identified this error.

Comment: Thanks Yann & Quentin for help  I will try to format right next time

Comment: And also note , if you use $ (document).one(), you will get the alert message only once at first click. Subsequent clicks will be ignored

Comment: @TheGuest That is not true. The callback for tap event is not being registered through `.one` .

Comment: @lorefnon The question is already answered. So I am just reminding the function of one(), not answering the OP's question

Comment: Thanks again I will learn to use developer tools and be more patient in checking spelling  & syntax

Comment: It was just a spelling error works now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few problems in your code. First, change `scr` to `src` in your script tag:

```
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
```

Second, you probably just want to use `$(function)` instead of the event you're using now. Third, it's best to put reusable functions outside anonymous functions (such as your event handler).

Here's the code changed to do what you want:

```
$(function () {
    $('#submitAdd').on('tap', addWalk);
});

// I moved this function outside the other function.
function addWalk() {
    alert(1);
}
```

Comment: one is a valid api method : http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: @lorefnon: Ah, that's news to me. I haven't used jQuery in many years. :)

Comment: @lorefnon damn, I didn't grok that :) Well said

Comment: Downvoters; scr is STILL misspelled

Comment: I don't understand the downvote though, I still believe the suggested code is an improvement to the previous one. Using `on` or `one` has no difference in the proposed case, and `$(…)` is still more reliable for on page load events.

Comment: I didn't downvote the post. Also jQuery mobile actually recommends pageinit rather than domready (ie. $(...)) : https://api.jquerymobile.com/pageinit/

Comment: I see. Unless this is specifically a jQuery mobile project I'd stick with `$(…)`. As that documentation states, `pageinit` is deprecated by `pagecreate`, which is part of a `page` widget. I don't think it's necessarily the best solution for a web page.

Comment: hmm ... that makes sense. @Changnoy please mark this answer as accepted using the check button on left side.

Comment: @lorefnon thanks for pointing out how to accept question

Answer (score 0):

With above suggestions by various other,
Also make sure , you have a `<body>` in your html page and in that you should have a "id" with "submitAdd" like below. (Since your javascript suggest , that you are registering and event with submitAdd")

```
<body>
<div id="submitAdd">
tap here </div>
</body>
```

And finally once it the page load happens you are registering the function with the tap event with the submitAdd element. Thus the function goes not get automatically called but only when the event occurs

Answer (score -1):

Please make sure your script.js file is loading. You can see that in the developer tools in chrome.

Comment: It is not because src is misspelled.

Comment: yeah , others had mentioned it above, to contribute, it would be the script.js not loading. many a times who use the local system ( not a server) would make mistake putting the js file in a folder called js, and refer it from <script src="js/script.js" > and hope it would magically link it.